# How to extract text from several .txt files with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to programming and using Python, and I couldn't find anything on here that quite answered my question. Basically what I'm looking to do is extract a certain section of about 150 different .txt files and collect each of these pieces into a single .txt file.

Each of the .txt files contains DNA sequence alignment data, and each file basically reads out several dozen different possible sequences. I'm only interested in one of the sequences in each file, and I want to be able to use a script to excise that sequence from all of the files and combine them into a single file that I can then feed into a program that translates the sequences into protein code. Really what I'm trying to avoid is having to go one by one through each of the 150 files and copy/paste the desired sequence into the software.

Does anyone have any idea how I might do this? Thanks!

Edit: I tried to post an image of one of the text files, but apparently I don't have enough "reputation."

Edit2: Hi y'all, I'm sorry I didn't get back to this sooner. I've uploaded the image, here's a link to the upload: https://i.stack.imgur.com/us9JA.jpg

Comment: What is the sequence that you want to extract?

Comment: You'll need to show us some sample inputs.

Comment: Are these are fasta files or sequence alignment files? You may get better advice on [biostars](https://www.biostars.org/).

Comment: Post a link to the image. Someone with more reputation can incorporate it directly into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you have 150 fasta files and in each fasta file you have sequence id that you want its sequence. you could use Biopython module to do this, put all your 150 files in a folder such as "C:\seq_folder"(folder should not contain any other file, and txt files should not be open)

```
import os
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq

os.chdir('C:\\seq_folder') # changing working directory, to make it easy for python finding txt files 
seq_id=x # the sequence id you want the sequence
txt_list=os.listdir('C:\\seq_folder')
result=open('result.fa','w')
for item in txt_list:
   with open (item,'rU') as file:
     for records in SeqIO.parse(file,'fasta'):
          if records.id == seq_id:
               txt.write('>'+records.id+'\n')
               txt.write(str(records.seq)+'\n')
          else:
               continue
result.close()
```

this code will produce a fasta file including the sequence from your desired id from all the files and put them in 'result.fa'. you can also translate them into protein using Biopythn module.